# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, oracle

```
System.out.println("Enter the code: ");
Code=input.next();                       
System.out.println("Enter the title: ");
Title=input.next();   
System.out.println("Enter the semster: ");
Semester=input.next(); 
System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
Year=input.next();           
System.out.println("Enter the grade: ");
Grade=input.next(); 

String insertStatement ="insert into Courses values('"+Code+"'+'"+Title+"'+'"+Semester+"'+'"+Year+"'+'"+Grade+"')";
System.out.println(insertStatement);
s.execute(insertStatement); 
continue;
```

When I insert the values and run the code, it shows me

```
insert into Courses values('GET'+'CS'+'Fall'+'2016'+'C+')
```

Error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

could someone explain for me? thank you

Comment: Some tips: variable names should almost always be lowercase (Code should be code, Year should be year etc)...also look into the `PreparedStatement` class. It is very bad practice to concatenate variables into an sql string directly

Comment: Why concatenate into a single string? Don't you want to pass 5 separate values to Oracle? `String insertStatement ="insert into Courses values('"+Code+"','"+Title+"','"+Semester+"','"+Year+"','"+Grade+"')";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your SQL statement to use columns name like this:

```
String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Courses (codeColName, titleColName, semesterColName, yearColName, gradeColName)"
                + "VALUES ('" + code + "', '" + title + "', '" + semester + "', '" + year + "', '" + grade + "')";
```

, best practice to use `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: @user13016777 check the updated syntax and if the column text keep the quote if numeric remove if

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the query correctly, Your double quotes are messed up.

You need something like this:

```
"insert into Courses values('"+Code+"'"+"'"+Title+"'"+"'"+Semester+"'"+"'"+Year+"'"+"'"+Grade+"')"
```

But yes, it is prone to SQL injection so it is better to use the PreparedStatement